# Are there any notebooks of famous mathematicians, through which we can understand their thinking and learning process?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, book-recommendation, big-list, research, mathematicians

Please name some published/preserved notebooks of famous (or not so famous) mathematicians, which you think reflect their learning or thinking process.

Notebooks which contain mistakes are highly requested.

Comment: I'm a not famous mathematician ,whos notebook is filled with error

Answer (score 2):

Well, Ramanujan's notebooks contain quite a few mistakes. However, he didn't generally provide proof along with his theorems, so it's really just a list of theorems. If I'm not mistaken though, he later went through them with Hardy and added some proofs. Even today, people are still working through his notebooks and proving his theorems. A lot of the proofs can be appreciated with just high school algebra too.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [this](https://www.maa.org/press/books/sophies-diary) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0684859807), or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0684859807). None are really journals but I think some are close to permitting us to see into the minds of mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

The *Recoltes et semailles* of A. Gothendieck is not a notebook in the conventional sense, but it is not a formal, polished paper too. It's something between the two -- although with a lot of personal stuff and some nonsense mixed in; but who doesn't dawdle in their books in those moments of apparent boredom?

Answer (score 1):

[Les archives Bourbaki](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/archives-bourbaki/) give a fascinating overview of Bourbaki's working methods and thinking process.